# #1093 - You can't specify target table 'rent' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql-error-1093

"UPDATE rent SET remaining='$remnow' WHERE date=(select max(date) from rent where shopno='$shopno')";

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 'from rent' in your UPDATE statement.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```